# FTDI (FT232R) chip holding the RX line high

Tags: rs232, ftdi

The issue that I am having is that the device won't communicate.
I have traced the problem down to the RX line on the FTDI chip holding itself high and not letting signals through. I have spent a couple of hours looking for answers in the datasheet but the only hint that I got is that when the chip is resetting it will hold the RX line high. 
This is not a faulty chip as I have tried replacing it.
I have also checked for shorting between the pins of the FTDI and found nothing.
This is also an issue that is affecting multiple PCBs, so it is unlikely that it is a random fault. It is likely a problem with the design. 
here is a link to the datasheet: https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf

Also here is a diagram of my circuit.

[image: Circuit layout]

Comment: Did you try a simple loopback test?

Comment: as in send it something and see where it fails? Yes, I have sent test signals and they get through the ftdi to the micro. However, the micro can't respond back because the RX pin on the FTDI chip is holding the line high.

Comment: are you sure it is the FT232 and not something else? Do you see a small drop in the RXD signal when the micro is attempting to drive it? (I would expect at least hundreds of millivolts or even a a volt or two if there is contention). The adjacent pin (Pin 4) is VCCIO - is there a solder bridge?

Comment: I disconnected the rx pin on the ftdi to check. the ftdi pin is what is holding it high

Comment: Desolder the chip and checkout the board.  Note that RX is right next to VCCIO.  Consider swapping parts with something known to work like a usb logic serial cable or an Arduino clone... good chance *those* are fakes but if they work it at least changes the variables and you can see if the issue follows the chip or the board.

Comment: FTDI has a pull-up on RX pin. After desoldering it, connect it to TX pin for a loopback test. I suggest verifying that the RX pin is connected to correct TX pin on the MCU and that the MCU is properly configured (when RX is desoldered, transmission on MCU TX hould be seen on oscilloscope if the problem was the FTDI).

Comment: To pickup chamod loopback idea up again: did you try to disconnect the µC (or even make a board with only the FT+its components on it), connect FTs RX with TX directly and send a test message? If you receive it back it is not an problem with the FT. If you dont receive it...welp maybe pin out error or counterfeit

Comment: I have followed your instructions and done the loopback with the rx and tx soldered together. I was able to receive the text back through putty. Though this has only confused me further. when I connect the tx and rx the line drops to 1mV.

Comment: @ChristianB. Could you please submit your comment as an answer. your explanation on how to properly perform a loopback test was the catalyst for solving this problem and I would like to give you credit.

Comment: one can upvote comments as well as far as I know. Out of curiosity: what was the solution/reason for the observed behaviour?

Comment: @ChristianB. The only option I see for comments is flag as a problem. I included what i did to solve the problem as an answer. I am hesitant to select it as THE answer because i want to give credit.

Comment: added an answer. I see a triangle over each flag with the info text "This comment adds somthing useful to the post" but maybe this option only "non question authors".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally it is good pratice to check each part seperately and verify its functionality in such a case. Basically it is similar to the "unit tests" in programming while the "putting together part" is analogous to the "integration tests".

As the device is recognized by the computer and the TX is working according to the comments I would suggest to pickup chamod loopback idea up again: did you try to disconnect the µC (or even make a board with only the FT+related components), connect FTs RX with TX directly and send a test message? If you receive it back it is not an problem with the FT. If you dont receive it it might be a pin out error.

Answer (score 3):

It is with extreme embarrassment that I have come to inform you all that this problem was actually caused by an incorrect firmware being loaded onto the microprocessor that was communicating with the FTDI chip. I do not consider this a complete waste as I have learned some new troubleshooting steps from you all that I did not know before. 
I thank you all for your time and effort.

Comment: Congratulations, a solution is a solution.  That the actual location of the problem isn't what one might first guess is not at all unusual.

Comment: So why did you not mark this as the accepted anwer?

Answer (score 0):

The UART protocols often have an option for inverted logic levels to make it easier to convert into RS232 voltage levels. FTDI chip is no exception - both RXD and TXD signals can be independently inverted in configuration. Connect to the chip with configuration utility and check the settings.

Having said that, I don't understand how RXD can "hold the line high". RXD is an input and AFAIK it does not even have a pull-up. If you see steady voltage on it try pulling it to GND with 1k resistor. If this does not work your chip is probably busted.

Edit:

As @Justme pointed out, pins do have weak pull-ups when configured as inputs. So, try that 1k pull-down and see if it changes things. If not then something is wrong with your boards.

Comment: Just gave this a try and it was a no go. The line still held 3.3v either way.

Comment: I've updated an answer

Comment: I initially believed that it might be damaged as well. However, 4 out of 4 of these PCBs that I have are having this problem.

Comment: Is it possible you have the pins mapped wrong somehow?

Comment: FTDI does have a weak pull-up so the part about it having no pull-up is false.

Comment: @Justme You are correct, it seems input pins do have 200k pull-ups. In which case my suggestion to try 1k pull-down makes even more sense. Also... labeling a statement with "AFAIK" as false is a little bit harsh, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I see on [FT232R datasheet](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf) page 8 :

> RESET# (pin 19)
>   Active low reset pin. This can be used by an external device to reset
>   the FT232R. If not required can be left unconnected, or pulled up to
>   VCC.

But try to put RESET# pin to high level
[image: Reset PIN for FT232RL]
Hope this help

Comment: The data sheet states Reset can be left open.

Comment: @KevinWhite Yes but face to spurious reset, I will try to fix the pin status to known state to remove some problems

Comment: I agree, I like to pull those sort of signals to an appropriate direction, but they wouldn't cause a solid error.

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know.

Comment: I have given this a try and it did not fix the problem

Comment: @Michael, ok where did you buy your chip ?

Comment: I don't actually know. We had these made with a turnkey process. They are closed now but I would have to call them to find out where they purchased the IC.

Comment: @Michael turnkey manage and mount by PCBWAY ?

Comment: @rom1nux No its a place called Active Electronics Manufacturing.